# Is it possible to create/modify/delete login info in a QB Desktop file via the QB SDK (or any other programmable method)?

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, qbfc

We are an accounting office and would like better control over user accounts on several hundred client QB files. Is there any way to use the SDK (or other tool) to create/modify/delete the login accounts (including changing passwords) for a given file?

QB Desktop 2016 or later, especially Accountant edition.

(I know there is a QB Password vault in the accountant edition, it doesn't do what we need)

(This question is strictly about the Desktop version, I am not interested in QBO-related answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible through the SDK.